# Seaborn/matplotlib: Create new named styles/themes for distribution and reuse?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn has several named, built-in style themes that can be set using `sns.set_style()`, e.g. `sns.set_style("whitegrid")`. Can this list of named styles be extended? I would like to be able to create a package containing additional named styles, so that a user could type something like:

```
import seaborn as sns
import fancy_seaborn_styles
sns.set_style("fancy_style_foo")
```

Seaborn documentation details many ways that adhoc customizations can be applied, but (as far as I can find) does not cover how to collect these customizations into named, reusable styles.

Trivially, I can write a new function that simply executes whatever settings changes I would otherwise make inline for all my plots, which is what I do now. But ideally I would like to retain compatibility with all the ways styles can be set in Seaborn, such as applying to a single subplot ax:

```
fig = plt.figure()
with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"):
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

If extending this exact interface is not possible, is there some other recommended way to package new Seaborn/Matplotlib styles for reuse or distribution? Are there any examples of third-party libraries that extend Seaborn with styles beyond the built-in ones? I’ve been searching for any examples in hopes that I might copy their implementation but I’ve been unable to find any at all.

Comment: Are you aware of the [customizing](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) tutorial? This essentially shows all you need to know about building and using your own styles.

Comment: Thank you — this explains how to customize styles for a single site installation by modifying local config files, which is helpful. What I am unsure of is how to package these customizations so that they can be used by others after installing a Python package. (Note that the styles added by Seaborn do not require the user to manually save or modify any local configuration beyond installing/importing Seaborn and calling `sns.set_style("nameofstyle")` — this is what I’m hoping to achieve.)

Comment: You cannot use `seaborn.set_style`; instead you need to use the methods shown in the link above. If you want to package your styles, let them be copied to the config directory during setup (`matplotlib.get_configdir()`).